# --follow-tags doesn't seem to be working on `git push`

Tags: git

Here's my repro:

```
$ mkdir git-test
$ cd git-test
$ git init
$ echo "hello world" >> test_file.txt
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "made a change"
$ git tag v1.0.0
$ git push -u --follow-tags origin master
```

Now if I go to my upstream repo, it has the commit but *not* the tag!

> ```
>    --follow-tags
>        Push all the refs that would be pushed without this option, and also push annotated tags in refs/tags that are missing from the remote but are pointing at committish that are reachable from the
>        refs being pushed.
> ```

That's from the man pages. Maybe I'm misunderstanding what `--follow-tags` does, but shouldn't it have pushed my `v1.0.0` tag when it pushed the commit to upstream?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> push **annotated tags** in refs/tags that are missing from the remote but are pointing at committish that are reachable from the

`git tag v1.0.0` created a lightweight, non-annotated tag. Delete it and create an annotated tag:

```
$ git tag -d v1.0.0
$ git tag -a v1.0.0
```